# Chosen jquery plugin adding more options than there are in select

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

This is the first time time I am having problems with this plugin.

I have these options:

```
<select name="booking[adult]" id="booking-adult" style="display: none;" class="chzn-done">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

And I get this via chosen:

```
<ul class="chzn-results">
<li style="" class="active-result" id="booking_adult_chzn_o_0">1</li>
<li style="" class="active-result" id="booking_adult_chzn_o_1">2</li>
<li style="" class="active-result result-selected highlighted" id="booking_adult_chzn_o_2">3</li>
<li style="" class="active-result" id="booking_adult_chzn_o_3">4</li>
<li style="" class="active-result" id="booking_adult_chzn_o_4">5</li>
<li style="" class="active-result" id="booking_adult_chzn_o_5">6</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, it adds two '

` elements.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle for your problem http://jsfiddle.net/MJMM3/

It is running perfectly over there. It might give you a clue of what you doing wrong.

The code for your reference:

```
<select name="booking[adult]" style="width:200px;" data-placeholder="Choose a number..."     id="booking-adult" tabindex="-1" class="chosen-select">
<option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
```